# Simple NameError, does not make any sense?

Tags: python, nameerror

```
File "F:\Samuel's Python.py", line 86, in Code
    userScore2 == questionsCorrect

NameError: name 'userScore2' is not defined
```

I am confused however because this is the first time in my code that 'userScore2' is accessed and this should define it.

I was wondering if there was something I was missing as I am relatively new to Python and if so how can I fix it. I have tested this same code with different variables E.G.

```
Number1 == Number3
```

And I received the same error.

Comment: `==` is a comparison operator not an assignment operator.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assignment is `=`. Comparison is `==`. You can assign to new variables but you can't compare them. Change your code to:

```
userScore2 = questionsCorrect
```